# which is the better place to initialize the base class member variables?

Tags: c++

```
class A // abstract class
{
protected:
    int m_iA;
    int m_iB;
    int m_iC;
    int m_iD;
    int m_iE
    ~A();
};

class B : public A // abstract class
{
protected:
    double m_dA;
    double m_dB;
    double m_dC;
    double m_dD;
    ~B();
};

class C : public B
{
public:    
    C(int iA, int iB, int iC, int iD, int iE, double dA, double dB, double dC, double dD)
    {

    }
}
```

**Question**> As you can see above example, both base class `A` and `B` contain many member variables. What is the better solution to pass those initial values from class `C` up to the base classes?

Method1> Assign the base class member variables directly inside the constructor body of class `C`.

Method2> Pass all initial values from constructor of `C` to `B`, and then finally to `A`.

Thank you

Comment: There is a third option you didn't mention: Pass (const references to) fully-constructed objects of type A and B to C's constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend making constructors for A and B, and have them take the initialization values, and apply them.  Then C calls B's constructor, passing values to it, and so on.  This way if there is ever another class inheriting from B or A, it follows the same pattern, and this can be enforced, by only having constructors that require initialization values.

Comment: You make a very good point - if A or B adds a new member, adding a new parameter to the constructor ensures that they're properly constructed or you'll get compile errors.

Answer (score 2):

Create constructors for the base classes that take initialization values, and use them in `C`'s constructor initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

Using C++11, you can get away with a bit less overhead than you expected:

```
class A { // abstract class
protected:
    int m_iA;
    int m_iB;
    int m_iC;
    int m_iD;
    int m_iE
    A(int iA, int iB, int iC, int iD, int iE)
      : m_iA(iA), m_iB(iB), m_iC(iC), m_iD(iD), m_iE(iE) {}
    ~A();
};

class B : public A { // abstract class
protected:
    double m_dA;
    double m_dB;
    double m_dC;
    double m_dD;    
    B(int iA, int iB, int iC, int iD, int iE, double dA, double dB, double dC, double dD)
      : A(iA,iB,iC,iD,iE), m_dA(dA), m_dB(dB), m_dC(dC), m_dD(dD) {}
    ~B();
};

class C : public B {
public:
    using B::B;
}
```

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks for the hint. I tried to make the *punchline* more visible by collapsing some lines (now you don't have to scroll anymore).

Answer (score 1):

The better idea is to take a `tuple`, `array` or custom struct which contains the initialization values, and then unpack it in the constructor for B and A. Then C's constructor only needs to take two objects.

Comment: It's certainly an alternative.  It may or may not be a "better idea" depending on the particulars.

Answer (score 0):

Having such a long constructor in the first place is... not preferable, but regardless:  Either way works equally well, I would say it is a matter of personal choice.